# Flutter State Management (BloC): Stateless vs Stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart, stateless, bloc

So I am reading through `Bloc` for state management for `flutter`.

Since Bloc allows you to sink and stream (rebuilding a widget based on the input), then is it possible to build an app mostly with stateless widgets?

As an example, let say I make lots of single stateless class widgets, thus almost everything is compartmentalized into its own stateless widget.

With the Bloc state management, I could simply rebuild a certain stateless child widget to reflect the change.

In this approach, I don't see the need of using the stateful widget. Of course, being a total beginner in `flutter`, I wanted to hear if this approach has any merit to it.

Is this a good approach? Any info will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to use provider pattern, lot simpler and supports streams as well, and you can use either statefull or stateless widgets  not taking provider into consideration.

Comment: Yeah, I looked into provider pattern, but there seems to be a general consensus that it is not ideal for a complex app, and rather good for a prototyping as it has a limitation of separating presentation and business logic apart. Might as well start off with Bloc.

Comment: You write Provider classes, and all the state is managed in a central place specific to a type, it doesn't get mixed up. Look into Flutter channel on Youtube, where they convert the app from Bloc to Provider, and the amount code/complexity reduction you get. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrBiNHEqSYU

Comment: That's a good resource! I will definitely check it out. Thanks buddy! =)

Comment: That "general consensus" that provider doesn't scale is wrong. Pretty much any popular state management solution use provider anyway. Even bloc.

Comment: Still, there are such cases, where you need StateFullWidgets Like you are adding Animations, If you have TextFields, etc. In such cases, stateful widgets are a way to go.

Comment: Useful read for all the types of state management https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're right that you can use only StatelessWidgets. You just need to be cognizant of where you create your bloc. Some ways of instantiation are more easily testable than others, like passing the bloc to your StatelessWidget as an argument.

But for implementation, I like the `flutter_bloc` library the best:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

It includes `BlocProvider` which automatically handles creation and disposal of blocs.

One other thing to note is that you'll often have to kick off an event in a bloc to perform some action and a `StatefulWidget` could be useful to run that in the `initState` method.

You could either say in a `StatefulWidget`:

```
initState(){
   _myBloc = SomeBloc()..add(SomeEvent());
}

// Then somewhere in your widget tree
BlocProvider<MyBloc>(
  create: (context) => _myBloc,
  builder: (context, state) {},
)
```

OR, in your `StatelessWidget`:

```
BlocProvider<MyBloc>(
  create: (context) => MyBloc()..add(SomeEvent()),
  builder: (context, state) {},
)
```

You'll find what works best for you, but I've found with Flutter that it mostly depends on the situation and goal of a particular feature. There's no need to pin yourself into a habit of always needing to use a StatelessWidget, but you are right that it is possible.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I had found this answer 3 hours ago ;-)

Answer (score 9):

You can use only Stateless Widget. But there is one problem that you should close streams before the app is disposed of. It can be handled in two ways:

1. First, you can use a Stateful widget and close streams of bloc in the dispose method of stateful.
2. Using BlocProvider. In this case, Bloc Provider is a Stateful widget only. It closes streams automatically. Then you can use bloc using BlocProvider in Stateless Widget.

But it doesn't mean that we don't need stateful widgets. Stateful widgets are important in animation for example. Animation, text input or any local changes in the widget itself shouldn't be handled in bloc or other state management. it is the duty of widget itself.

Comment: but text input can be controlled by bloc with RX streams they support to merge two streams and some useful operations, but for animation, it should be developed.